# Why is my word cloud not showing all the data involved?

Tags: html, d3.js, word-cloud

Anyone familiar with creating word clouds in d3 and html able to tell me why my code below is not showing all the IDs in the word cloud? The values represent the average product ratings for each product ID. So the size of each word would be dependent on the ratings. Thanks in advance!

Please see code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Programming Assignment 2 Visualization</title>
        <div id="worddataviz"></div>
        <style>
          html, body, #worddataviz {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;}
        </style>
    </head>
     <body>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
        <script>
            var productrating = [
                {ID:'B001E4KFG0', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B00813GRG4', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B000LQOCH0', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B000UA0QIQ', value:'2'},
                {ID:'B006K2ZZ7K', value:'4.75'},
                {ID:'B000E7L2R4', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B00171APVA', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0001PB9FE', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0009XLVG0', value:'3'},
                {ID:'B001GVISJM', value:'4.4'},
                {ID:'B00144C10S', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0001PB9FY', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B003F6UO7K', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B001EO5QW8', value:'4.21'},
                {ID:'B000G6RPMY', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B002GWHC0G', value:'4.5'},
                {ID:'B004N5KULM', value:'4.67'},
                {ID:'B001EO5TPM', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B005DUM9UQ', value:'4.4'},
                {ID:'B000E7VI7S', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B001GVISJC', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B006SQBRMA', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0059WXJKM', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B001EPPI84', value:'1.5'},
                {ID:'B004X2KR36', value:'4.33'},
                {ID:'B005R8JE8O', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0066DMI6Y', value:'4.5'},
                {ID:'B003ZFRKGO', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0019CW0HE', value:'4.53'},
                ];

                var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
                    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                    
                var svg = d3.select("#worddataviz").append("svg")
                            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                    
                var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
                                      .size([width, height])
                                      .words(productrating.map(function(d) { return {text: d.ID, size:d.value}; }))
                                      .padding(5)
                                      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
                                      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.value; })     
                                      .on("end", draw);
                    layout.start();

                function draw(words) {
                    svg.append("g")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
                       .selectAll("text")
                       .data(words)
                       .enter().append("text")
                       .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.value; })
                       .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
                       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                       .style("font-family", "Impact")
                       .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                        })
                       .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
                    }
               
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample has some errors (mostly with managing the coordinates).

See my attempt to solve them in the snippet below:

```js
var productrating = [
                {ID:'B001E4KFG0', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B00813GRG4', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B000LQOCH0', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B000UA0QIQ', value:'2'},
                {ID:'B006K2ZZ7K', value:'4.75'},
                {ID:'B000E7L2R4', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B00171APVA', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0001PB9FE', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0009XLVG0', value:'3'},
                {ID:'B001GVISJM', value:'4.4'},
                {ID:'B00144C10S', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0001PB9FY', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B003F6UO7K', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B001EO5QW8', value:'4.21'},
                {ID:'B000G6RPMY', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B002GWHC0G', value:'4.5'},
                {ID:'B004N5KULM', value:'4.67'},
                {ID:'B001EO5TPM', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B005DUM9UQ', value:'4.4'},
                {ID:'B000E7VI7S', value:'4'},
                {ID:'B001GVISJC', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B006SQBRMA', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0059WXJKM', value:'1'},
                {ID:'B001EPPI84', value:'1.5'},
                {ID:'B004X2KR36', value:'4.33'},
                {ID:'B005R8JE8O', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0066DMI6Y', value:'4.5'},
                {ID:'B003ZFRKGO', value:'5'},
                {ID:'B0019CW0HE', value:'4.53'},
                ];
                
               const words = productrating.map(d => Object.create({text: d.ID, size: parseFloat(d.value) * 100}));

               
                var svg = d3.select("#worddataviz").append("svg")
                            .attr("width", 300)
                            .attr("height", 200)
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(150, 100)");
                    
                var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
                                      .size([300, 200])
                                      .words(words)
                                      .padding(2)
                                      .rotate(() => Math.random() * 180)
                                      .fontSize(d => d.size / 50)     
                   
                                      
                    layout
                      .on("end", () => draw(layout.words()))
                      .start();
                    
                   

                function draw(words) {
                    console.log({words});
                  
                    svg
                       .selectAll("text")
                       .data(words)
                       .enter().append("text")
                       .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.value; })
                       .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
                       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                       // .style("font-family", "Impact")
                       .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y}) rotate (${d.rotate})`)
                       .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
                       
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
        
<div id="worddataviz" />
```